How to Convert a List of Unevaluated Expressions into a List of Expression Objects in R
I am working on a problem in R where I need to convert a list of unevaluated expressions into a format where each element is explicitly wrapped within an expression() object. The expressions involve variables that are not yet defined in the environment. Here are the details of the formats involved:
Input format:
my_list <- list(A = a + b, B = b^2)
Desired output format:
list(A = expression(a + b), B = expression(b^2))
The key challenge is that the variables a and b are not defined when the list is created, and I want to avoid any evaluation of these expressions during the conversion. The conversion must handle the expressions such that they are ready for later evaluation, while remaining unevaluated in their new form.
There is requirment that we cannot use the dots (...) as the input is only a single unevalauted list object.
I tried finding a solution in Hadley's book "Advanced R", but there was no information on how we could take an unevaluated object and convert it to subexpressions (there were some clever tricks with dots, but we have the restriction that all the calls be already packed into the list class object).
I also tried ChatGPT, which gave me confidence that we are still very far from when AI will completely take over our jobs.

why not use list(A=expression(a + b), B = expression(b^2))? or alist(A = a + b, B = b^2)?

Your question does not make sense. You just stated convert a list of unevaluated expressions Do you have that list? Is your goal conversion or creation? If conversion, could you give the dput of the list you want to convert? If creation, well use alist

This is the whole point: I need to transform a user-inputted list() object to sub-expressions to be able to evaluate these later upon requests of the specific expressions.
Inputting expressions as a list(A = expression(a+b), ...) or a list (A = a + b, ...) directly would be much easier, but here, we are limited to the single argument following the strict form, which is alist(A = a + b, ...) which we need to find out how to transform to list(A = expressions(a + b), ....)

So are you looking for a function that users would call as fx(list(list(A = a + b, B = b^2)), or possibly fx(A = a + b, B = b^2), to return your desired output? The "input" you provided in your post, my_list <- list(A = a + b, B = b^2) obviously throws an error as written, so please clarify.

You also seem to say you’re starting with "a list of unevaluated expressions," but (1) that isn’t clear in your example input and (2) if so, it sounds like you already have your desired endpoint, ie, a list of expressions.

I find some "dirty" solution to this issue (see my comment below). You may rerun the code, and it may get easier to understand the purpose of this and the desired result. The description of this problem may not be very clear, but the problem itself is unusual; therefore, it is hard to explain in a single post.

Your requirements are a tad vague but based on your attempted solution I think you need the following:
expression2listed_expressions = function (expr_list) {
  expr_list = substitute(expr_list)
  expr_list[[1L]] = quote(alist)
  eval(expr_list)
}

Basically: use alist() instead of list(); and if you can’t control how the function is called then you can take the unevaluated input and replace list() with alist() in the syntax tree.
Alternatively you can omit the evaluation altogether: substitute() already makes your input unevaluated — you only need to extract it from the list() call node in the syntax tree (the as.list() converts the sub-expression from a call into a regular list):
expression2listed_expressions = function (expr_list) {
  expr_list = substitute(expr_list)
  as.list(expr_list)[-1L]
}

Note that this doesn’t return a list of expression objects. You can trivially wrap the result into expression objects, but this is probably unnecessary.

Thanks! This solution is so simple and smart. Much better than the string expressions I wrote below. It solves the problem!

What source of "user input" ?  Your example will not be accepted in the first place.  Perhaps require your users to write
 my_input <- c('a+b',  ''b^2')
my_list <- list(A = expression(my_input[1], B = expression(my_input[2]))


Input is an unevaluated list.
Thanks for taking a look at the problem.
I find a quasi-solution to it - see my commentary below.

Via the use of the frustrating regexpr, I managed to find the solution. It is not the most elegant but at least it works now.
expression2listed_expressions <- function(expr_list) {
  
  # converting the call to string
  expr_string <- rlang::as_label(rlang::enquo(expr_list))
  
  # Strip the 'list(' prefix and the closing ')'
  cleaned_string <- gsub("^\\s*list\\s*\\(|\\s*\\)\\s*$", "", expr_string, perl = TRUE)
  
  # Split the string into separate assignments
  assignments <- strsplit(cleaned_string, ",\\s*(?=[A-Z]\\s*=)", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
  
  result_list <- setNames(lapply(assignments, function(assignment) {
    parts <- strsplit(assignment, "\\s*=\\s*", perl = TRUE)[[1]]  
    name <- parts[1]
    expr <- parts[2]
    (parse(text = expr))
  }), sapply(assignments, function(assignment) {
    strsplit(assignment, "\\s*=\\s*", perl = TRUE)[[1]][1]
  }))
  
  return(result_list)
}

res <- expression2listed_expressions(list(A=a+b, B = b^2, C = mean(c(a, b))))

a <- 1
b <- 2
eval(res$A)
eval(res$B)
eval(res$C)


a <- 5
b <- 25
eval(res$A)
eval(res$B)
eval(res$C)


your function body should be as.list(substitute(expr_list)[-1]) that all your function should contain
